# Problems activating worksheet in excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

My macro's were working perfect in excel 2010, but in 2013 I have a major problem with activating workbook in vba and than when certain sheet is selected + cell is selected I can fill in data, but when pressing enter or arrow key, the data is set to the first visible page of my file.
This happens when I activate another workbook, but also in the same workbook when I select a certain sheet, the data entered will go to the first sheet... what has changed from excel 2010 to 2013 that makes this happen??

this is the code I use:

```
Workbooks(MachineInspectieLijst & ".xlsm").Activate
Workbooks(MachineInspectieLijst & ".xlsm").Worksheets(MachineInspectieLijst).Range("V5").Select
```

When I fill in a value in V5 and enter, the value disappears and shows up on V5 in first page...mostly.

When I manually switch between the pages or workbooks, than it works... I founnd nowhere an answer.

hope somebody has the answer.

Comment: when you activate your workbook, it goes in the last sheet you were in it last time you were there. So you will also need to make the wanted sheet your activesheet. Or else you'll end up writing stuff in the wrong page. Still V5 will be selected in the page you wanted but you won't be on that page with your code. Nethertheless, i recommend to never use activate or select. you might also want to disable events by adding application.enableevents=false at the begin of the code and reset to true at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Do the process sequentially:

```
Sub hfjsdfh()
    Workbooks(MachineInspectieLijst & ".xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets(MachineInspectieLijst).Select
    Range("V5").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the actual sub, I tried your suggestion, but exactly the same...Indeed, it is like the second workbook is not really activated, but how to solve? has it to do with the userform who stays loaded? this one must stay loaded, as it contains lot of necessary information and is only unloaded at new start. Nevertheless, I tried to unload as test, but same problem. Can it be due to excel itself?

Private Sub CmdGetInspectionList_Click()
Dim thesentence As String
Dim WB As Workbook
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Dim WB2 As Workbook
frmKlantSelectie.Hide
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Me.cboDocumentType.Value = "Sales Budget Quotation" Then
     MachineInspectieLijst = "Machines_Sales"
     WB.Worksheets("PreInspArticles").Range("J1") = "Sales"
Else
     MachineInspectieLijst = Me.cboInspectieMachine.Value
End If
loginnaam = StrConv(WindowsUserName, vbUpperCase)
thesentence = "C:\Users\" & loginnaam & "\Dropbox\2_Doc_Service\DATA\Pre_Inspection_Checklist\" &      MachineInspectieLijst & ".xlsm"

'checken ofdat de file wel bestaat in de directory
 If Dir(thesentence) <> "" Then
     MsgBox "Machine Check list exists! Press 'OK' and file will be shown!"
'Test to see if the file is open.
    If IsFileOpen(thesentence) Then
       Workbooks(MachineInspectieLijst & ".xlsm").Activate
    Else
 'Display a message stating the file is not in use.
    Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(thesentence)
 End If
  Else
     MsgBox "No machine selected Or Check list not yet existing."
     frmKlantSelectie.Show
     Me.TxtInspectionList.SetFocus
  Exit Sub
  End If
    WB2.Worksheets(1).Range("V5").Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True

  End Sub
```